# Default value or NULL in Room database entity

Tags: android-room, setdefault

I'm trying to understand Room database library. I am struck with a scenario where two tables are linked via **@ForeignKey constraint**. What I need is, when the parent row is deleted, all the child columns in the child table should be set to NULL or some default value. But when I tried to use

```
onDelete=SET_NULL or SET_DEFAULT with @ForeignKey
```

I get the following error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint
>   failed: Log.tagId

From the error I can see that the child column has been set as **NOT NULL** during the table definition, can someone say how to change it to be **NULLABLE** since room creates the tables for us? Also, it is ok if we can set a standard default value on the columns. If so, how to set the default value of columns? I think there should be some way else the constants **SET_NULL** or **SET_DEFAULT** has no meaning and purpose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check this really good article here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1 , where there is a Note: "In Room, SET_DEFAULT works as SET_NULL, as Room does not yet allow setting default values for columns.".